# How to say "What was your favourite subject" and "tell me something interesting about you"

Tags: translation, mandarin

I want to know how to say "What was your favourite subject" (i.e. school subject when younger) and "tell me something interesting about you" in Mandarin.

Would it be something like: 你最喜欢的科目是什么 and the when younger is implicitly implied?

Google translates the second phrase as: 告诉我一些关于你自己的有趣的事情 I'm not sure if this is a natural way to say ask the phrase?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a job interview.

Comment: What do you mean by "and the when younger is implicitly implied." The translations are fine.

Comment: @Mo. is there a more casual way to say it?

Comment: @River I was meaning that from the context the other person would probably understand I am talking about when they were younger (if they are no longer in school as they are an adult)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are causal ways:

> What was your favorite subject?

你上学的时候最喜欢什么课？

- 你上学的时候：time indicator
- 什么课："subject" 科目 would be the same as "course" 课 for a student. "课" is more casual than "科目"

> Tell me something interesting about you.

你有没有什么有意思的特点？说来听听。

- 有意思：causal version of 有趣
- 特点：characteristic of a person
- 说来听听：causal way to say "tell me"
- This question is rarely asked by Chinese, as far as I know. We usually don't advertise ourselves by attaching interesting things and features to ourselves. Instead, we usually ask/talk about experiences, like "tell me an interesting experience of you." 你有没有什么有趣的经历？说来听听。